# Show that the Lebesgue measure $|K|\neq \lim_{n\to \infty} |E_n|$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]=\{q_1,q_2,\dots\}$. Let $K=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (q_n-3^{-n}, q_n+3^{-n})$ and $E_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: dist(x, K)<\frac{1}{n}\}.$ Show that the Lebesgue measure $|K|\neq \lim_{n\to \infty} |E_n|$.

---

Note that
$$
|K|\le \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{2}{3^n}=1
$$

I am stuck on how to deal with $|E_n|$... It seems that we need to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |E_n|>1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|K|$ is strictly less than $1$. This is because $(q_1-3^{-1}, q_1+3^{-1})$ must overlap with some other $(q_k-3^{-k}, q_k+3^{-k})$.

However, $[0,1]\subseteq E_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: How to show that $[0,1]\subset E_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: @H.YDuan The question is for any real $x\in[0,1]$ do the rationals come arbitrarily close to $x$? The answer is yes.

Comment: I can understand intuitively that but how to write it rigorously? For any $x\in [0,1]$, how to get $x\in E_n$?

Comment: @H.YDuan Suppose $n$ is fixed. For a given $x\in[0,1]$ we want to find an element $\beta\in K$ such that the distance between $x$ and $\beta$ is less than $1/n$. Yet $K$ contains all rational numbers in $[0,1]$, and these rationals get arbitrarily close to $x$.

Comment: I got it. So $|E_n|\ge 1$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|E_n|\ge 1>|K|$?

Comment: @H.YDuan that is right!

Comment: Oh...One more question. So for $x\in [0,1]$, there is a rational number $\beta\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ so that $|x-q_n|<\frac{1}{3^n}$? Then $x\in (q_n-3^{-n}, q_n+3^{-n})$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @H.YDuan No that is not true. The condition wanted is that some element of $K$ is close to $x$. The condition wanted is not about $x$ being contained in $K$.